# What is the maximum control surfaces deflection on a Cessna 210N?

Tags: aerodynamics, control-surfaces, cessna-210-centurion

Does someone know how far the control surfaces (rudder, ailerons, elevator and nose gear) can deflect in a Cessna 210N? I've been searching Google and the POH for hours now and can't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best source for such information (for e.g. simulation purposes) is the **maintenance manual.** I found one* for the 210 and T210 series (1977 to 1984, which includes the **N** model; [models overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_210_Centurion#Variants)):

- AILERON TRAVEL

  - Up 20° ±2°
  - Down 15° ±2°
- WING FLAP TRAVEL (Electrically-Actuated)

  - 0° ±0° to 30°, +1° -2°
- RUDDER TRAVEL (Measured parallel to water line)

  - Right 24° ±1°
  - Left 24° ±1°
- RUDDER TRAVEL (Measured perpendicular to hinge line)

  - Right 27° 13' ±1°
  - Left 27° 13' ±1°
- ELEVATOR TRAVEL

  - Up 23° ±1°
  - Down 17° ±1°
- ELEVATOR TRIM TAB TRAVEL

  - Up 25° ±1°
  - Down 10° ±1°

---

* [PDF](http://data.tmorris.net/aviation/poh/rsv/doc/cessna-maintenance-manuals/Cessna_210&T210_1977_1984_MM_D2057-3-13.pdf); ~60 MB; see PDF page 15 (page "1-3")

Comment: `"I found one for the 210 and T210 series"` - would be great if you could add the link !

Comment: thank you ! one last question - how far does the nose gear rotate to each side ?

Comment: @Programmer: The nose wheel steering is connected to the rudder and the rigging for both is done in reference to the rudder travel limit. It doesn't mention the wheel travel, but you can assume it's the same as the rudder *hinge line* figures but applied to the steering axis.

Comment: @Programmer: BTW, once the nose wheel is in the air [it doesn't turn with the rudder](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/52510/14897).